# Как с помощью маски SVG сделать плавный переход от одного изображения к другому

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animation, mask

Допустим, у меня есть многоцветный градиент, который заполняет экран

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600" >  
  <defs>
  <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">

        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#503969" />  
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
       <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
  </linearGradient> 
   </defs> 
   <rect  width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />  
  </svg>
```

И изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать анимацию градиента с помощью маски SVG, чтобы появилось изображение дракончика?
Градиент должен плавно раздвигаться на две половинки, показывая изображение

Answer (score 8):

**Решение реализовано на свойстве SVG масок прорезать объект, к которому применена маска с элементами закраски `fill="black"`**

На первом слое расположены цветные градиентные полосы. Выше этого слоя расположено изображение.

```
<rect  width="600" height="600"  fill="url(#grad)"  />  
          <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhtOM.jpg" y="-60" mask="url(#msk1)" width="800" height="780" />
```

Если бы к изображению не была бы применена маска `mask=”url(#msk1)”`, то было бы всегда видно только изображение, так как градиентные полосы расположены под изображением.
 Но к изображению применена маска, состоящая из двух прямоугольников, которые имеют `fill=”black”`, делая тем самым маску полностью прозрачной и показывая тем самым, нижний слой с градиентными полосами. При анимации раздвигания половинок маски, становится видно изображение.

*Анимация раздвигания, сдвигания половинок градиента начнется после клика*

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 600 600">  
  <defs>
  <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">

        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#503969" />  
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
       <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
  </linearGradient>
     <!-- Маска -->
  <mask id="msk1" > 
        <rect  width="100%" height="100%"  fill="white" /> 
          <!-- Анимация левой половины маски   -->
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="600" fill="black" >
           <!-- Анимация правой половины маски   -->      
   <animate attributeName="x" begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" values="0;-300;-300;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
    </rect> 
      <rect x="300" y="0" width="300" height="600" fill="black" >
       <animate attributeName="x" begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" values="300;600;600;300;300" fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
    </rect>
  </mask>
     </defs>
   <rect  width="600" height="600"  fill="url(#grad)"  />  
       <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhtOM.jpg" y="-60" mask="url(#msk1)" width="800" height="780" /> 

</svg>
```

### Пример с радиальными градиентными полосами

В примере ниже в состав маски входят прямоугольник и окружность. Изменяя радиус окружности, можно менять размер круглой маски, увеличивая или уменьшая размер круглого отверстия сквозь, которое становится видимым нижнее градиентные полосы.

```
<!-- Маска -->
     <mask id="msk1" > 
        <rect  width="100%" height="100%"  fill="black" /> 
          <circle cx="300" cy="300"  r="0" fill="white" >
            <!-- Анимация маски прорезающей изображение и показывающей радиальный градиент             -->
           <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="0;300;300;0;0"
             fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
        </circle>
     </mask>
```

*Анимация раздвигания радиального градиента начнется после клика*

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 600" >  
  <defs>
      <!-- Многоцветный радиальный градиент -->
  <radialGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">

        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#503969" />  
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
       <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
  </radialGradient>
      <!-- Маска -->
  <mask id="msk1" > 
         <rect  width="100%" height="100%"  fill="black" /> 
    
    <circle cx="300" cy="300"  r="0" fill="white" >
            <!-- Анимация маски прорезающей изображение дракончика и показывающее радиальный градиент  -->
   <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="0;300;300;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
     </circle>
  </mask>
     </defs> 
            <!-- Фоновое изображение радиальный градиент   -->
   <circle  cx="300" cy="300"  r="300"  fill="url(#grad)"  />  
                 
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kywq.png" x="-140" y="-60" mask="url(#msk1)" width="800" height="780" />  

</svg>
```

### Третий пример

Используется два изображения: девушки и рассерженного льва

Этот пример аналогичен второму примеру.
На нижнем слое фоновое изображение льва.
На верхнем слое изображение девушки, к которому применена маска.

```
    <!-- Фоновое изображение льва, которое становится видно, через отверстие прорезанное маской -->
    <image id="img2" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5UFF.jpg" opacity="1" x="-60" y="-40" width="160%" height="160%" >

    </image>
            <!-- К изображению девушки применена маска -->
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/73YNh.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"
       pointer-events="fill" mask="url(#msk1)" />
```

Анимация маски достигается изменением `rx` эллипса.

```
<ellipse cx="300" cy="265" rx="0" ry="240"  >
           <animate id="open" attributeName="rx" dur="3s" begin="idefinite" 
               values="0;50;0;50;0;100;80;185" fill="freeze" /> 
             <animate id="close" attributeName="rx" dur="3s" begin="idefinite" 
                  values="185;0" fill="freeze" />
</ellipse>
```

*Анимация раскрытия изображения льва начинается после клика, закрытие изображения после повторного клика*

```js
var lion_svg1 = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  close = document.getElementById('close'),
  open = document.getElementById("open");

let flag = true;

lion_svg1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (flag == true) {
    open.beginElement();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    close.beginElement();
    flag = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="400" height="400"   viewBox="0 0 600 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <!-- Ко всему изображению применён белый цвет маски, поэтому всё пространство вне элипса становится видимым -->
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />   
      <!-- К эллипсу применен чёрный цвет маски, поэтому на этом участке изображение вырезается --> 
     <!--  и становится видным другое, нижнее изображение   -->
  <g fill="black" >
      <ellipse cx="300" cy="265" rx="0" ry="240"  >
     <animate id="open" attributeName="rx" dur="3s" begin="idefinite" values="0;50;0;50;0;100;80;185" fill="freeze" /> 
       <animate id="close" attributeName="rx" dur="3s" begin="idefinite" values="185;0" fill="freeze" />
   </ellipse> 
 </g>  
 </mask>
 </defs>  
 
     <!-- Фоновое изображение льва, которое видно, через отверстие прорезанное маской -->
 <image id="img2" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5UFF.jpg" opacity="1" x="-60" y="-40" width="160%" height="160%" >
    
 </image>
            <!-- К изображению девушки применена маска -->
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/73YNh.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"
       pointer-events="fill" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>
```

### Четвёртый пример

Анимация прозрачности маски

Как и в третьем примере два изображения:
нижнее, в качестве фона льва
к верхнему изображению девушки применена маска в форме овала

*Анимация маски достигается за счет анимации прозрачности овала.*

```js
var lion_svg1 = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  close = document.getElementById('close'),
  open = document.getElementById("open");

let flag = true;

lion_svg1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (flag == true) {
    open.beginElement();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    close.beginElement();
    flag = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="400" height="400"   viewBox="0 0 600 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <!-- Ко всему изображению применён белый цвет маски, поэтому всё пространство вне элипса становится видимым -->
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />   
      <!-- К эллипсу применен чёрный цвет маски, поэтому на этом участке изображение вырезается --> 
     <!--  и становится видным другое, нижнее изображение льва   -->
  <g fill="black" > 
             <!-- Анимация прозрачности маски -->
      <ellipse cx="300" cy="265" rx="185" ry="240" opacity="0"  >
     <animate id="open" attributeName="opacity" dur="3s" begin="idefinite" values="0;1" fill="freeze" /> 
       <animate id="close" attributeName="opacity" dur="3s" begin="idefinite" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />
   </ellipse> 
 </g>  
 </mask>
 </defs>  
 
 

     <!-- Фоновое изображение льва, которое видно, через отверстие прорезанное маской -->
 <image id="img2" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5UFF.jpg" opacity="1" x="-60" y="-40" width="160%" height="160%" >
    
 </image>
            <!-- К изображению девушки применена маска -->
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/73YNh.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"
       pointer-events="fill" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>
```